# webpack plugins not considered to be constructors

Tags: webpack

In my `webpack.config.js` in plugins property, I have these plugins included:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  new webpack.HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: 'React App',
    filename: 'main/index.html',
    inject: 'body'
  }),
  new webpack.UglifyJsPlugin(),
]
```

What I don't understand is, when I run the webpack, it threw an error that says:

> C:\Users\Welcome\Desktop\app\webpack.config.js:45
>           new webpack.HtmlWebpackPlugin({
>           ^
>
> TypeError: webpack.HtmlWebpackPlugin is not a constructor

I followed every steps of the tutorials I watched but I still always fail. How can I make this execute successfully?

Answer (score 1):

They switched the syntax without telling anybody. Checkout [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567930/typeerror-cleanwebpackplugin-is-not-a-constructor) on the cleanwebpackplugin.

Answer (score -1):

try first setting a var for each plugin

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
```

then define them without specifically saying they are part of webpack

```
plugins: [
  ...
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'React App',
      filename: 'main/index.html',
      inject: 'body'
  })
  ...
],
```

Comment: Should I install it as a dependency or a devDependency? 'Cause it's a dependency in my `package.json`. Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: hmm, now that I look, it seems that you are using it correctly, however that error seems to be implying you cant pass an object of arguments into it. Their github pages begs to differ but I'm not familiar with this plugin. Sorry. Did you install with npm?