# TypeError: CleanwebpackPlugin is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

i'm trying to preview a vue web application through webpack-server-dev.I'm following this guide 
https://medium.com/the-web-tub/creating-your-first-vue-js-pwa-project-22f7c552fb34

The guide explains that the plugin is used to delete old and unused files in the dist directory. I have already tried replacing `const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')` with `const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')` which some posts suggest. i have also tried looking at the documentation on https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin but without succes as i am pretty new to this.

when i try to `npm run dev` i get this error

```
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    ^

TypeError: CleanWebpackPlugin is not a constructor
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\webpack.config.js:56:5)
    at handleFunction (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\prepareOptions.js:21:13)
    at prepareOptions (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\prepareOptions.js:9:5)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:119:14)
    at C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:125:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:79:40)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

and this is the webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path')

const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
  mode: argv && argv.mode || 'development',
  devtool: (argv && argv.mode || 'development') === 'production' ? 'source-map' : 'eval',

  entry: './src/app.js',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  node: false,

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
        exclude: /\.module\.css$/
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.vue',
      '.json'
    ],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static', 'index.html'),
      inject: true
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
      to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      toType: 'dir'
    }])
  ],

  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      minSize: 30000,
      maxSize: 0,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        }
      }
    },
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: entrypoint => `runtime~${entrypoint.name}`
    },
    mangleWasmImports: true,
    removeAvailableModules: true,
    removeEmptyChunks: true,
    mergeDuplicateChunks: true
  },

  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    https: true,
    open: true,
    overlay: true,
    port: 9000
  }
});
```

this is the error i get when using the right import as explained in the documenation :

```
      throw new Error(`clean-webpack-plugin only accepts an options object. See:
      ^

Error: clean-webpack-plugin only accepts an options object. See:
            https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin#options-and-defaults-optional
    at new CleanWebpackPlugin (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\clean-webpack-plugin\dist\clean-webpack-plugin.js:27:13)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\webpack.config.js:56:5)
    at handleFunction (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\prepareOptions.js:21:13)
    at prepareOptions (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\prepareOptions.js:9:5)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:119:14)
    at C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:125:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Eson\Desktop\pwa-vue-app-1\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:79:40)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

if i delete line 56 in webpack.config.js i can run the web application without problems, but i want to understand the source of this issue

Comment: do u have webpack config file?

Comment: i added the webpack.config.js file i'm using to my post

Comment: What's the error message when you use [the correct import](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin#usage)?

Comment: The documentation shows the constructor as taking an object, and you are trying to give it an array. Have you tried making the changes suggested by the documentation as well as getting rid of that invalid parameter?

Comment: You are probably using latest version of clean-webpack-plugin (v3). Please use clean-webpack-plugin (v1) to make it work.

Comment: So your problem, when fixing the config file to be correct for the latest version, is that you are not calling the constructor correctly. You need to pass an *object* to the constructor, not an *array*.

Comment: @SachinSingh That is a horrible idea. Go down *two* major versions instead of just fixing the problem? NOPE! If one wanted to *avoid* the problem for now, one would just need to go back a version on the plugin, not change what version of webpack is being used.

Comment: I have added my error when using the correct import. The error is now narrowed down to what @crashmstr suggests. How do i correctly make the Cleanwebpackplugin to delete my unused distributed files directory 'dist' as (['dist']) doesn't seem to be the right way to do this

Comment: I'd suggest just removing that and using the constructor without parameters, then see what, if anything, is not behaving as you expect. The plugin should normally clean the "dist" folder (or whatever is configured) without any additional configuration.

Comment: @crashmstr I have suggested the version based on your configuration. Of course it's a horrible idea to go down a version. I would suggest to follow the official documentation of clean-webpack-plugin in that case instead of seeking answers from other sources. Here's the github link for you: https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin

Comment: Using the constructor without paramater works but sadly i wont be able to test if it does its job. I did learn what was causing the problem and how to fix it, thanks for your help and time guys!

Comment: @crashmstr Sorry! I did not realize that ECallpani actually asked the question. My answer is addressed to him instead. Anyways, thanks for your input. On a second thought, going down a couple of versions is not a horrible idea in my opinion. Clean webpack plugin version 1 is a major release and compatible with webpack 4. Going up a version can be problematic since it can introduce breaking changes. If you are setting up for the first time, then it's recommended to always use the latest version.

Answer (score 134):

The correct one is to use this import:

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
```

And then instead of passing an array with the distribution folder, change it to

```
plugins: [
     new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
     //...
]
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but i still get the error: CleanWebpackPlugin is not a constructor

Comment: @AKJ what version of the plugin did you use?

Comment: @AKJ try to delete first the node_modules folder, then redownload the packages.

Comment: I am using version ^1.0.1. I managed to get it to work by simply doing this: const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin'); Without the curly braces.

Comment: @AKJ you're using a lower version, you might experience this once you upgraded to version 3.0.0

Comment: @AKJ Did you change `new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])` to `new CleanWebpackPlugin()`?

Comment: The braces seem to be the important bit

Answer (score 55):

I had the same problem, and I solved it in the following way：

```js
    const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
```

```js
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['dist']
        })
    ]
```

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue today, right now. As you can tell, there was a mismatch between the docs and the actual code. And in fact, you can see in [the last commit they merged](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin/commit/d0e34084e20f0a0f0857d117d665f5ee8536dfa5#diff-d267fc81ff4f0d44271784a40c7819e6) both to the documentation:

[image]

and also to the code:

[image]

So I just switched from `const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')` to

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
```

and it works fine.

I think you may have been caught in between things. Reinstall the npm package and try again, it should work.

I wrote a bit of what you can see in their public repository because very often when sudden changes like this happen, you'll **find your own answer in the repo**, probably in the last commits. And it's good reading a bit of the code you use, especially if it helps you troubleshoot your issue :)

Answer (score 17):

With the update you'll need to do the following to include it

`const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');`

Then in the array of plugins, replace the following configuration

```
plugins: [
     new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
]
```

with

```
plugins: [
     new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
]
```

As the with the update there is no need to pass any parameters as it will remove all files inside webpack's `output.path` directory, as well as all unused webpack assets after every successful rebuild.

Answer (score 9):

For those finding this error with the recent updates to **nativescript-vue**, I fixed it by changing `webpack.config.js` (top level file in app folder).  As above, it now reflects the syntax in the CleanWebpackPlugin [docs](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin).

```
//const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
  const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
```

and

```
//new CleanWebpackPlugin(itemsToClean, { verbose: !!verbose }),
  new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
```

Answer (score 8):

When import, use { CleanWebpackPlugin } instead of CleanWebpackPlugin

This happens when the version is more than 1.

Example:

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
```

Answer (score 4):

CleanWebpackPlugin  v3.0.0

**Replaced default export with named export CleanWebpackPlugin**

[https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin/releases/tag/v3.0.0]

correct code is:

```
// es modules
import { CleanWebpackPlugin } from 'clean-webpack-plugin';

// common js
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not very much familiar with webpack and currently learning it

although this thing below helped me fix the issue

I just uninstall clean-webpack-plugin and then reinstall as dependency 
before this i've intalled as a dev-dependency

after uninstall and installing it like that : npm install --save clean-webpack-plugin

and by adding this

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
```

solved my issue!!

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today, I figured out that I also had to remove `webpack.config.js` file.

After deleting the file, i had to rerun `npm install`

-> Application started successfully.

--

Inside `webpack.config.js` some old references were placed.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a weird outlier reason for this - but I just came across this while setting up an old project on a new linux machine.  It turned out I didn't have dev dependencies installed for my project (by default if npm config is set to production it won't install dev dependencies when running npm install - although I'm not sure exactly why mine was set to production), my webpack cli is 4 but my project is at 2.6.1 so it was using the webpack 4 but my webpack.config was for 2.  So make sure your dev dependencies are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack v5 doesn't need cleanwebpack. Use output.clean: "true".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Be also aware of writing it like this

```
const {
    CleanWebpackPlugin
} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
```

and not like this :

```
const {
    cleanWebpackPlugin
} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
```

In my case that small letter C was an issue. It is class name of this plugin which is being imported, so there is no place for arbitrariness in naming.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like docs are broken, correct code is

> const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

Comment: correct variant for webpack > 5 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57016146/13760371